# How to copy Oldest file to new directoy?

Tags: powershell

I need a script to move 1 old file to another directory.
I have a script but is not good for me:

```
$path = "C:*.*" 
$Destination = "C:*.*" 
Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $path)) { 
  If($file.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).adddays(-1).date) { 
    Move-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $Destination 
  } 
}
```

I need only 1 file, and Oldest every day.

Please help, Thanks

Comment: this is mt worng script $path = "C:\*.*"
$Destination = "C:\*.*"
Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $path))
{
 If($file.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).adddays(-1).date)
 {
  Move-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $Destination
 }
}

Comment: Please do not post information that is relevant for your question in comments. Instead [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one file then you don't need a *foreach* loop there. You can try something like this using the ***Sort-Object*** and the ***Select-Object*** with the *-Descending* parameter.

Presently I have sorted that with the *CreationTime* and you can always choose the first element of the resultant using the *-First*.

```
$path = "C:*.*"  ;
$Destination = "C:*.*" ;
$file= Get-ChildItem $path | select name,lastwritetime,CreationTime | sort-object -property CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 ; 
  If($file.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).adddays(-1).date) { 
    Move-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $Destination 
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
$path = "C:\temp"  ;
$Destination = "C:\temp\olddir\" ;
Get-ChildItem $path -file -rec | 
    where {$_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).adddays(-10).date} | 
        Select-Object -First 1 |
             Move-Item -Destination "$Destination"
```